# How to upload images or files in Next.js app deployed to Vercel

Tags: next.js, mern, vercel, cloudinary

When I upload images from localhost, it works perfectly. But when I deploy the Next.js app to Vercel, and try to upload files or images throug cloudinary it does not work. How can I solve the problem?

I want that the pictures or files will perfectly upload with vercel as well as will store to cloudinary.

Comment: maybe give some more details of your issue or some examples of your upload methodology, i am currently facing the same issue

Comment: Vercels file size limit on serverless functions - like you are probably using for uploading - is around 4 - 5 MB.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
import { v2 as cloudinary } from "cloudinary";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

// Cloudinary config
cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: "your_cloud_name",
  api_key: "your_api_key",
  api_secret: "your_api_secret",
  secure: true,
});

export const POST = async (req) => {
  
  const data = await req.formData();
  const image = await data.get("image");
  const fileBuffer = await image.arrayBuffer();

  var mime = image.type; 
  var encoding = 'base64'; 
  var base64Data = Buffer.from(fileBuffer).toString('base64');
  var fileUri = 'data:' + mime + ';' + encoding + ',' + base64Data;

  try {
    
    const uploadToCloudinary = () => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

          var result = cloudinary.uploader.upload(fileUri, {
            invalidate: true
          })
            .then((result) => {
              console.log(result);
              resolve(result);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
              reject(error);
            });
      });
    };

    const result = await uploadToCloudinary();
    
    let imageUrl = result.secure_url;

    return NextResponse.json(
      { success: true, imageUrl: imageUrl },
      { status: 200 }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("server err", error);
    return NextResponse.json({ err: "Internal Server Error" }, { status: 500 });
  }
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).